# SQL Server 2005 Connection Issue

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Just an odd problem with my SQL server this morning...  Locally I am able to connect to the SQL Server Studio but unable to view tables, etc when I am on theserver.  I am able to connect however from other workstations using the same login, and able to view tables etc.  I don't believe any settings or major upgrades were made.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Which account are you connecting as locally vs. remotely?  SQL 2005's Manglement studio remembers the last login used, so if you've got a no-privilege user's credentials left in there, you may not get to see as much as you do when connecting as Admin/sa/whatever.
I got freaked out by this when I accidentally connected as a reporting user and started stressing about where all the tables had gone.

Comment: Locally on the server administrator was being used to login to windows server 2003, then inside the SQL Management Studio sa was being used.  Remotely, both sa and other users can login.  
It really only happens using the administrator on the 2003 server.